# How to get updated records from Oracle in C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, oracle12c

I am trying to get latest updated records by comparing day and time. When I run my query on stored procedure it give the correct result but when I run the query on my ASP.NET MVC, it only compares day and not the time and does not provide me with the correct results. How can I run and compare day and time on Oracle using C#.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have not sended date paramter as correctly in your .NET application to database. Did you try format date parameter before call your SP?

```
var param = new OracleParameter("paramNameSP", OracleDbType.Date, 
ParameterDirection.Input);
param.Value = yourDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Comment: Do not do this. **Do not pass dates as strings**.